# awk seperate field based on length

Tags: awk

I have a field containing rows similar to:

```
HEJ;DU;NORDEN;13322;90
ER;HER;NOGEN;334333;1
```

I want to output a file where $4 (which can be 5 or 6 digits) is split into two seperate fields, depending on the lenght
if 5 the split should be 3-2, if 6 the split should be 3-3

So the output should be

```
HEJ;FRA;NORDEN;133;22;90
ER;HER;NOGEN;334;333;1
```

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to make that seperation ?

I have been toying around with awk and gsub, and it works if I do it just for the field, but then the hazzle is to get it back aligned with the other fields, and I haven't managed to realize how I can embed the gsub function into an expression where it only touches one column of data ?

Comment: Kindly wrap your samples into code tags. Also add whatever you have tried in order to fix this issue(which you mentioned in your post that you have tried).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `substr` function.

```
first = substr($4,1,3)
second = substr($4,4)
$4 = $first ";" $second
```

You don't need a conditional, since the first part is always 3 digits long.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** More simpler approach.

```
awk -F";" '{sub(/^.../,"&" OFS,$4)} 1' OFS=";"  Input_file
```

Not checking conditions like column's length is 5 or 6, in case you want to do it then we could add those too in above code.

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F";" -v s1=";" '
{
  $4=length($4)==5?substr($4,1,3) s1 substr($4,4):length($4)==6?substr($4,1,4) s1 substr($4,5):$4
}
1' OFS=";"  Input_file
```

Comment: It doesn't - it treats the seperator as space (?) - and divides the other way around. (tried to paste it, but for some reason it wont let me do linebrakes (even with <br>)

Comment: @LeifHvitved, check now, added `OFS=";"` it should help here.

Comment: @LeifHvitved, see my EDIT solution more easier now :)

Comment: You can reuse the OFS variable there: `sub(/.../, "&" OFS, $4)`